# How can I infer a type based on key name?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible to infer the type by property name?
The following example shows a simple interface called `DataType`. Another generic interface `ColumnType`.

The `ColumnType` includes a `style` property - a function that receives one parameter - an object of type `CallbackParamsType`. This type includes the property `cellValue: any`. How can I make the cellValue type be inferred according to the type in DataType?

For example, the style function of the column object with `propertyName: name` should infer `cellValue` as string because `DataType.name` is string.

How can it be achieved?

```
interface DataType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
  type: "FT" | "QA";
}

const allData: DataType[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "one",
    quantity: 1,
    price: 1,
    type: "FT",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "two",
    quantity: 2,
    price: 2,
    type: "QA",
  },
];

//

interface CallbackParamsType<T> {
  cellValue: any;
  rowValue: T;
  data: T[];
}

interface ColumnType<T> {
  header: string;
  propertyName: keyof T;
  style?: (params: CallbackParamsType<T>) => Record<string, string>;
}

const columns: ColumnType<DataType>[] = [
  { header: "Id", propertyName: "id" },
  {
    header: "Name",
    propertyName: "name",
    style: ({ rowValue, cellValue }) => {
      const x = cellValue;  // this type should be string - because DataType.name is string
         // ^?
      return {};
    },
  },
  {
    header: "Quantity",
    propertyName: "quantity",
    style: ({ rowValue, cellValue }) => {
      const x = cellValue;  // this type should be number - because DataType.quantity is number
         // ^?
      return {};
    },
  },
  {
    header: "Price",
    propertyName: "price",
  },
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAKgTwA4oDeAUMssACYBcyAzmFKAOYDcpyIcAthDfYyFbsAjgFc44YGBw0QorgCNobMnkZJZ8pVBXJpBGgCIAYlkPIAPskMBFAIKG2AX2LEEAexD1kcADa-0TBpA7HwIAG0AXWQAXmRw9hIyMkojAEZDABp2Mk4eI08ILJzkMQkwKRlkNOzk5DVgDWra5P1ea1NisicWpOTU6wAmLuS89sMwAHd3EbIyyWkaQZbVdXblkrajexGe4ki2YgB6I9dQSFhEFABhP18FRABrAAU4KG5aXAIAHiwAPmQfSQ-gAan5RO0JDhdFB3JMwb4ITQsLoKBg4Mios4zuBoPAkMhru5EVwQF8IL8AX0ABYQOAUaB8BjMXRqdwEKDSABy3HajwgOHcMGQKPY9BwvggAH4aAAKPBvD40W7+B4IF6KrifMKUgCUsQBACUIB4oBRvvxmJk6MzBH9sW5PN4PCSvMrifIyTqQuS-lFYvFEshafTGdYAJIULL1WEc7m8oyUcx7Mh9MghhlQIw8nizGPs6Dx-LWMZ58WSuWEZCw+HgiDW4G+BEQ5BOfUxKklMgeLxgZAADwDjebEBYZBOempwFoejCdGp7lEvgoyCUNoETGQAFpVya4KJaCgfWEAHRjcgzy2CLt1CcAPSlN6gEDAoigIEBTl03RaKcBJQzMNbHEBYcDzNk4xwHNxnmCppDLaQK2QWUqxrEcGwgUE61bdtOzqbsnT7Qc4mHOsx2QCcwCnGc2nnRdl13DgtGgbddwQfdDzQdFyRPWDKgvJjFGgG9knvR98OrF83w-QgvxKP8-zTYM6UzIxnjWcDY0LKCE2sBokF2bIDiAA)

Comment: You'd need the key to be part of the generic, e.g. https://tsplay.dev/wQq0Aw is a step closer (both `cellValue`s are `string | number`).

Comment: thanks for that approach, but as you said it's a step closer but not yet what I'm looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating a union of the allowed types. First, I mapped the properties of `DataType` to their respective `ColumnType` and then I unionized them.

```
interface DataType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  price: number;
  type: "FT" | "QA";
}

const allData: DataType[] = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "one",
    quantity: 1,
    price: 1,
    type: "FT",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "two",
    quantity: 2,
    price: 2,
    type: "QA",
  },
];

//

interface CallbackParamsType<T, U> {
  cellValue: U;
  rowValue: T;
  data: T[];
}

interface ColumnType<T, U extends keyof T = keyof T> {
  header: string;
  propertyName: U;
  style?: (params: CallbackParamsType<T, T[U]>) => Record<string, string>;
}

type ObjValues<T> = T[keyof T];
type AvailableColTypes<T> = ObjValues<{
  [K in keyof T]: ColumnType<T, K>
}>;

const columns: AvailableColTypes<DataType>[] = [ 
  { header: "Id", propertyName: "id" },
  {
    header: "Name",
    propertyName: "name",
    style: ({ rowValue, cellValue }) => {
      const x = cellValue;  // this type should be string - because DataType.name is string
         // ^?
      return {};
    },
  },
  {
    header: "Quantity",
    propertyName: "quantity",
    style: ({ rowValue, cellValue }) => {
      const x = cellValue;  // this type should be number - because DataType.quantity is number
         // ^?
      return {};
    },
  },
  {
    header: "Price",
    propertyName: "price",
  },
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAKgTwA4oDeAUMssACYBcyAzmFKAOYDcpyIcAthDfYyFbsAjgFc44YGBw0QorgCNobMnkZJZ8pVBXJpBGgCIAYlkPIAPskMBFAIKG2AX2LEEAexD1kcADa-0TBpA7HwIAG0AXWQAXmRw9hIyMkojAEZDABp2Mk4eI08ILJzkMQkwKRlkNOzk5DVgDWra5P1ea1NisicWpOTU6wAmLuS89sMwAHd3EbIyyWkaQZbVdXblkrajexGe4ki2YgB6I9dQSFhEFABhP18FRABrAAU4KG5aXAIAHixM5AAqgA%20ZB9JD%20ABqflE7QBuig7kmUN8MJoWF0FAwcDRUWcZ3A0HgSGQ13cKK4IC%20EF%20-wByAgAA9ICAKLRkI8IDh3DBkFhYuzOdzeSC%20gALCBwCjQPgMZi6NTuAhQaQAOW4sN09BwvggAH4aAAKPBvD40W7%20B4IF4mrifMI03nhAGRIEASliIIAShAPFAKN9%20Mx-oHBEC8cQ2sgAPIKABWyJhtF%20ILiWHCHK5PKwBwjYWQdgAbnBgL44AodaTfFSk1gU9G4wmIEm%20uEANLkEACzO8yJmsnySn2v7IVtA4hOMOuDxeMDIDzkrw0QvF0vliCV6vfEJUoFRfnhZCJZDiyXS6wASQoWXqCKVqvVRko5j2ZD6ZBPUqgRjVPFmN8V0D3vk1hjH%20Wo6oahDIAiSLQhA-zgr4jbIE47oxCKJRkNO3gMvyiGNiwZAnHoorAGyka0KK7iiL4FDIEodCyoIyAALT0T6cCiLQKDbmEAB0YzkGyIZMJhdTEQAerqYlQBAYCiFAnaEE4ujdC0L6giUH5nrY4gLDgf4KneOA-uM8wVNIYHSBByAGlBMGNghECQnBKFoRhdRYZ4OF4c5SFwYRyDEWApHkXmlHUbR7EcFo0CsexCCcdxaBYlSfHmZUQkxYo0BickknSZ50FyQpSkqSUGkaW%20x4Sp%20RjPGshm3oBJkPtYDRILs2QHEAA)

## Explanation

### Mapped types

Typescript allows you to create indexed types like so:

```
type Rec = {[key: string]: number}
```

You can specify stricter key type, effectively mapping properties of another type to new values.

```
interface A {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
type keys = keyof A; // 'foo' | 'bar'
type mapped = {
  [K in keyof A]: boolean;
}
// {foo: boolean, bar: boolean}
```

The keys themselves can be transformed, e.g. to uppercase, and can be filtered. More on that [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

### Unions

Your requirements can be satisfied using unions.

```
type allowedCombinations = {prop: 'name1', value: string} |
  {prop: 'name2', value: number}; // etc

const example: allowedCombinations = {
  prop: 'name2',
  value: 'cat' // ERROR: must be a number
};
```

Just as keys of an object can be collected into a union using the `keyof` operator, so can be the values. This can be done like so:

```
interface A {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
type values = A[keyof A]; // string | number
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate a bit more? what does "mapped the properties" and "unionized them" mean?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the answer and add some more explanation